# where to save images generated by php before moving to cloud

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a laravel php app were a user is going to upload an image.  This image is going to be converted into a number of different sizes as required around the application and then each image is going to be uploaded to aws s3.

When the user uploads the image php places it in /tmp until the request has completed if it hasnt been renamed.  I am planning on pushing the job of converting and uploading the versions to a queue.  What is the best way to ensure that the image stays in /tmp long enough to be converted and then uploaded to s3

Secondly where should I save the different versions so that I can access them to upload them to s3 and then remove them from the server(preferably automatically)?

Comment: you need to move it from the system temp to your own, or it will be deleted

Comment: The /tmp he directory is cleared by default at every boot, because TMPTIME is 0 by default.

Here you can change the time in the following file:

/etc/default/rcS
TMPTIME says how frequent the tmp dir sould be cleared in days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a new directory and work on it. tmp folder is flushed every now and then depending on your system.

As for different sizes, i would create separate buckets for each size which you can access with whatever constant you use to store the image (ex: email, user id, etc..).